# How to use drag and drop to move files instead of copying

Tags: macos, finder, copy-paste

Drag and drop between drives defaults to copying the files not moving them. I know holding <kbd>⌘</kbd> along with the drag will move the files, but I'm looking for something more permanent like a `defaults` command, maybe?

I'm using Lion.

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is no `defaults` switch for this situation, otherwise someone would have helped already. But using the keyboard, you could **move** the files like this: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste at the desired destination. It’s like cut & paste on Windows, only Mac style. Also, works across volumes!